# Struts2 Convention Plugin Action Url

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using struts2-convention-plugin 2.3.1.2.

```
   <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
   <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="qqq"/>
   <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="zzz.yyy.xxx.action"/>
   <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
   <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="true"/>

   <package name="qqq" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
       <!--
         Some package configurations
       -->
   </package>
```

struts2.xml is configured as the above.

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>zzz.yyy.xxx.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

web.xml is as the above, and tomcat's context root is /foo.

**Quetstion**

I placed the LoginAction to zzz.yyy.xxx.action package,
and deployed the app, and I had the following result.

1. localhost:8080/foo/login -> OK
2. localhost:8080/foo/bar/login -> OK
3. localhost:8080/foo/bar/baz/login -> OK

I'm a little embarrased, because this behavior is not that I want.
I wanna only to permit the first case.
What should I do?

Comment: i believe(not sure) it is due to the namespace fall back mechanism S2 have, but this is just an idea and i myself have little exp with this plugin

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named struts.properties in "src" folder. And then add the line below to it.

```
struts.convention.action.suffix = Controller
```